# Train Test Split for a list of dataframes - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, train-test-split

I have a list of DataFrames that I want to split into train and test sets.
For a single DataFrame, I could do the following,

Get the length of test split

```
split_point = len(df)- 125
```

and then,

```
train, test = df[0:split_point], df[split_point:]
```

This gives me the train and test split.

Now, for list of DataFrames I could get test set length for each DataFrame using,

```
split_point = [len(df)-125 for df in dfs]  ## THIS WORKS FINE
```

I want to get the `train` and `test` split for the whole list of dataframes  as I have done for single dataframe. I tried the following,

```
train, test = [(df[0:split_point], df[split_point:]) for df in dfs]

## AND THE FOLLOWING

train, test = [(df[0:split_point] for df in dfs),(df[split_point:]) for df in dfs]
```

Both are not working. How can I do this?

(Some of the DataFrame's length might differ, but I am not worried about it as it will substract the 125 from the length, which I am considering for test set)

Comment: Your `split_point` is a list in your second case, why not just `list_of_trains, list_of_tests = zip(*[(df[0:len(df)-125], df[len(df)-125:]) for df in dfs])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
train, test = zip(*[(dfs[i][0:split_point[i]], dfs[i][split_point[i]:]) for i in range(len(dfs))])
```

Then each one of them would be a tuple with the corresponding parts of the data frames.

In the above code I am using

```
split_point = [len(df)-125 for df in dfs]
```

Just to make it more clear, consider the following more simple example:

```
r = [(i,i**2) for i in range(5)]
a,b=zip(*r)
```

Then `a` is `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)` and `b` is `(0, 1, 4, 9, 16)`.

Comment: When i try this I am getting an error `TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers ` any thoughts why?

Comment: @i.n.n.m I didn't notice that split_point is a list. See my updated answer.

Comment: follow up question, is `zip` method  the only way?

Comment: No, for example, you could just do each part separately:                       train=[dfs[i][0:split_point[i]] for i in range(len(dfs))] and test=[dfs[i][split_point[i]:] for i in range(len(dfs))]

Comment: got it, thank you! (I am fairly new to python trying to learn every way possible)